# Unsecure XMLHttpRequest calls from secure page

Tags: browser, xmlhttprequest, content-security-policy

in our company we need to implement a self hosted Rest Service that has to be deployed in the client workstations in order for our internal web applications to interact with them.
The web applications are in https, and we are not using, at the moment, the CSP headers.

Our concern is whether it's necessary to call the local service also in https or this can ne avoided (and so we can avoid to manage a certificate to deploy in every single workstation).

We made some trials with Chrome and Edge and it seems that the ajax calls are working also in plain http, but we would like to know if that is actually supported or not. Our internal web applications are not using, at the moment, the Content Security Policy headers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On an HTTPS connection browsers will block HTTP content as mixed content, CSP will not change that. However, Chrome will allow mixed content on http://127.0.0.1 and http://localhost while Firefox will allow it on http://127.0.0.1, see note on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content.

When you implement CSP you should include http://127.0.0.1 (or http://localhost) for the appropriate directive.